# iMac G3 installing Mac OS 9 error

Tags: imac, install, error, classic-mac-os, power-mac

I can't install Mac OS 9 on iMac G3. Installation process failed on "Starting Up..." stage.

[image: Text]

Comment: More detail needed. Has it been on the shelf unused for months or years? What install medium are you using (most likely CD) and what version is stamped on the install CD? When was the last time this iMac was booted up? What happens when you just turn it on -- what screen messages do you see? I would hazard a guess the internal HD is a brick, especially if it has been sitting on a shelf. Could be [the battery](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6119893) needs replacing - and perhaps the RAM needs reseating if possible. That's all I can diagnose from here at my desk somewhere on planet Earth.

Comment: I've been trying to reinstall the OS for years. On the first attempt, I also had this problem, but macOS 10.2 was successfully installed and now it starts and works with it, but very slowly. The battery is new. I don't have the original macOS CD, I'm using a CD burned with versions 9.0, 9.1, 9.2.2 and USB flash with boot kit 9.2.2, CD and USB flash failed at one stage.

Comment: I'm surprised the internal HD actually spins after all these years. You're lucky you were able to install macOS 10.2 to begin with. Does 10.2 still run on this iMac?

Comment: Yes, iMac works now with 10.2.

Comment: Perhaps you applied a [firmware update](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7907188) and the iMac can no longer accept a macOS lower than 10.2? It has been many years since I managed a fleet of these G3 iMacs, and my wetware RAM has started to degrade. :-)

Comment: I wonder if the install CD has something wrong with it? You said that it had multiple versions on it, I wonder if you can get at least a copy of the official Mac OS 9 install CD if that might work better that what you currently have.

Comment: No, I didn't. 10.2 was installed without any firmware updates ┐⁠(⁠ ⁠∵⁠ ⁠)⁠┌

Comment: May be, but where can I find it? I try all the disk images I find.

Comment: On one forum I found a moment about using non-RW CDs, CD-R only. I will try it soon. Also I wanna try with a clean hard drive. I ordered an IDE-USB adapter for it. Waiting for delivery.